# Struggle to make animation bounce effect on both "mountains" hitting the "sun"

Tags: css, animation

I did my first animated logo where blue and red mountains are "playing voley" with the sun in front of a canvas.

Creatively I am happy with the result but I wanted to ensure the animation timing function is such that sun is sort of "bounced" of the mountains.

The one on the left side does it perfectly right now, but then I can't figure out how to ensure the one on the right does the same as well.

I guess I should "split" my animation and avoid "alternating"?

How can I achieve that without rewriting a lot of code?

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"> <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="70 100 320 260"> <style> /* <![CDATA[ */ #canvas { fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 10; animation: canvas 1s infinite alternate; -webkit-animation: canvas 1s infinite alternate; } @keyframes canvas { 0% { transform: scale(1.0); -webkit-transform: scale(1.0); } 100% { transform: scale(0.95); -webkit-transform: scale(0.95); } } #sun { fill: rgb(248, 254, 141); stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 10; animation: sun 1s ease-in infinite alternate; -webkit-animation: sun 1s ease-in infinite alternate; } @keyframes sun { 0% { transform: translate(30px, 25px); -webkit-transform: translate(30px, 25px); } 50% { transform: translate(0px, 0px); -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px); } 100% { transform: translate(-30px, 25px); -webkit-transform: translate(-30px, 25px); } } #redmountain { fill: rgb(246, 198, 161); stroke: black; stroke-width: 10; animation: redmountain 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate; -webkit-animation: redmountain 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate; } @keyframes redmountain { 0% { transform: translate(10px, -5px); -webkit-transform: translate(10px, -5px); } 50% { transform: translate(0px, 0px); -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px); } 100% { transform: translate(10px, 5px); -webkit-transform: translate(10px, 5px); } } #bluemountain { fill: rgb(170, 226, 237); stroke: black; stroke-width: 10; animation: bluemountain 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate; -webkit-animation: bluemountain 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate; } @keyframes bluemountain { 0% { transform: translate(-10px, 5px); -webkit-transform: translate(-10px, 5px); } 50% { transform: translate(0px, 0px); -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px); } 100% { transform: translate(-10px, -5px); -webkit-transform: translate(-10px, -5px); } } /* ]]> */ </style> <path id="canvas" d="M113.72,157.88 Q245.96,160.52 335.00,155.00 Q344.84,243.08 379.16,330.20 Q249.80,286.28 86.84,332.12 Q104.84,253.64 113.72,157.88Z" /> <path id="sun" d="M169.25,171.82 C153.48,100.60 264.27,76.08 280.03,147.30 C295.80,218.52 185.01,243.04 169.25,171.82Z" /> <path id="redmountain" d="M282.86,245.68 Q305.23,282.77 335.36,341.75 Q272.53,336.63 201.75,337.86 Q231.77,304.97 282.86,245.68Z" /> <path id="bluemountain" d="M172.59,252.90 Q151.69,287.11 123.51,341.52 Q181.67,337.10 247.16,338.61 Q219.55,308.03 172.59,252.90Z" /></svg></div>
```